# Doctrine is in production environment but symfony is in dev

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, environment-variables

I'm working on an apache server (not in localhost) with symfony 4

I have my WebProfilerBundle bundle enable only in dev environment

My DoctrineBundle is enable everywhere

When I update (php bin/console doctrine:schema:update) I always get a

> [CAUTION] This operation should not be executed in a production environment!

Even if my APP_ENV=dev and even if I am can see my WebProfiler.

Someone know why ?

Comment: What's your Symfony version ? You can force the console env with the `--env` argument: `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --env=dev`

Comment: I'm working with symfony4. When I do what you say it's the same result as without flags. But I know how update my schema I can use --force I just wanna understand why doctrine work like in production

Comment: Actually, this is the expected behaviour. If you look into the Doctrine source code, it shows the caution message every time, regardless of the environment. Your command line is correctly executed on the dev environment. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are just 'dumping' the SQL that would be run, or you are explicitly adding the '--force' parameter, it will always [show the warning](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/c7718efff8f554b8e8e0f9fcda337ad265fd0b0e/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/Command/SchemaTool/UpdateCommand.php#L116).